# Best approach for desktop -> mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, actionscript, air

Im building an AIR desktop app. I have a bunch of information that id like to get to a cell phone so it can be accessed on-the-go rather than actually loading the app on your phone.  What is the best approach? E-mail it? Build a seperate mobile app that can load a xml file with saved data?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems a bit too broad for a good answer, especially without knowing anything about your app. Email is an easy solution but not very elegant. Building a separate mobile app is probably a much better user experience but also more work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question, with a lot of possible answers. In my opinion though, a user should have an account and you should have a separate mobile app in which all the data they input from their desktop is synced. This would require you to have a server that stores their data, and the extra work of creating the mobile app. Fortunately, since you are using AIR, you might be able to share a lot of the same code base with an AIR mobile app.

Another simple solution other than email could be something like a text message. Take a look at some services like https://www.twilio.com/ if you decide to go that route.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ended up using e-mail for now which works ok but like the previous post said, not very elegant.  
SMTPMailer - [link](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27)

I was thinking along the same lines as you for an account etc.. but then I run into costs for a server etc... Currently the app runs off XML but switching to sql shouldn't be a big deal.